# In Idris2, can't typecheck if then else directly

Tags: typechecking, idris, dependent-type

I'm a beginner with Idris. In Idris2 version 0.3.0, I observed a strange behavior.

Why doesn't this code type check ?

```hs
f : Type -> Type -> Type
f a b = (c : Bool) -> if c then a else b
```

```
While processing right hand side of f. Main.case block in f is not accessible in this context.
```

While this code type checks without issues:

```hs
f1 : Type -> Type -> Bool -> Type
f1 a b c = if c then a else b
f' : Type -> Type -> Type
f' a b = (c : Bool) -> f1 a b c
```

Is this a bug?

Initially, I was trying to prove a stupid theorem which should be obvious, but Refl doesn't work. It looks like it's unable to understand that the variables match.

```
module Main
import Data.Nat

t : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
t l r = if lte l r then l else r

prop : Nat -> Nat -> Type
prop a b = (t a b = if lte a b then a else b)

proof_prop : prop a b
proof_prop = ?imlost
```

Comment: your first snippet does type check for me with idris2 0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Your `if_then_else_` using program starts failing in [commit `04a0f5001f`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/commit/04a0f5001f87b531408640ed7edf9bff04e96abd):

> ## Correct multiplicities when checking Pi binders
>
> We've always just used 0, which isn't correct if the function is going
> to be used in a runtime pattern match. Now calculate correctly so that
> we're explicit about which type level variables are used at runtime.
>
> This might cause some programs to fail to compile, if they use
> functions that calculate Pi types. The solution is to make those
> functions explicitly 0 multiplicity. If that doesn't work, you may
> have been accidentally trying to use compile-time only data at run
> time!
>
> Fixes #1163

The solution is to mark your `f` function as type-level-only:

```
0 f : Type -> Type -> Type
f a b = (c : Bool) -> if c then a else b
```